# Limit 1 photo to display out of many - Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

How would I display one photo for a product, if there are many photos associated with the product. For example, I just need to display 1 photo in the front page, and i don't want to do a carousel. Here is what I have so far:

[image: My Product Images]

As you can see, im doing a for-each loop, and it is displaying all images associated with that product, I only want to display one image.

Here is how I'm displaying the images:

```html
@foreach($products->photos as $photo)                   
    <img src="/store/{{ $photo->thumbnail_path }}">
@endforeach
```

My Controller to display the Product for this page:

```html
class ProductsController extends Controller {


    /**
     * Show all products
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory|\Illuminate\View\View
     */
    public function showProducts() {
        // Get all products
        $product = Product::all();

        return view('admin.product.show', compact('product'));
    }

}
```

My Product Model (shortened):

```html
    class Product extends Model {

    /**
     * One Product can have many photos.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
     */
    public function photos() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\ProductPhoto');
    }

}
```

And this is how my Products Images Tables look like:

[image: My Images Table]

[image: My Products Table]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ditch the `@foreach` and use `first()` on the photos collection:

```
<img src="/store/{{ $products->photos->first()->thumbnail_path }}">
```

If you want to be able to choose **which** one's featured, you could add a boolean `featured` column to the photos table and do something like this:

```
public function featuredPhoto() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\ProductPhoto')->whereFeatured(true);
}
```

and:

```
<img src="/store/{{ $products->featuredPhoto->thumbnail_path }}">
```

Comment: Oh snapp, real nice Thank You!

Comment: @David You're welcome! You should also consider eager loading photos (or your app will make one query per row in that table to lookup the photos for each record). `$product = Product::with('photos')->get();` instead of `$product = Product::all();`. https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Comment: Alright I did that. Does that load the photos faster?

Comment: @David Yep. If you have a page that shows 50 products, `Product::all()` would produce **51 queries**, while `Product::with('photos')` will produce **two** queries for the same information. It's very important when displaying a list of Laravel models - I'd encourage you to read the linked doc for more details.